# How to print multiple list become one list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have this code:
the newlist is: [4,5,6,7,8]

```
    for i in newlist:
        ...:     if i < 7:
        ...:         x = [i]
        ...:         print (x)
        ...:         
    [4]
    [5]
    [6]
```

I want to have an output like this :
[4,5,6]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: [You must paste your code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) (and format it as code), not as an image.

Comment: You problem is solvable with a simple `print([4,5,6])` call. But I guess that's not what you want, so please explain in details what you expect from the code, what you have tried so far and where you got stuck!

Comment: Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Describe inputs, expected outputs, and the unexpected output, behavior and/or *exact* error(s) you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
newlist=[4,5,6,7,8]
l=[]
for i in newlist:
    if i<7:
        l.append(i)
print(l)
```

This gives the output you require
The problem with your code is:
x=[i],that means you are creating an array with single element at once.And also you are printing each element in a separate line which is not required.So as in my code,creating a newlist and appending values to it would give you one single array.Printing that array after iterating through your original array would give you the required output.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list=[4,5,6,7,8]
lis=[]
for i in new_list:
    if i<7:
        lis.append(i)
print(lis)
```

This is the code is suggest for that problem. The problem with your code is you just kept x=[i] which rewrites the existing value again and again ..........